# Object creation in Java is slow

Tags: java, object

My experience shows that object creation in Java is very slow. Often, I optimize my code by just removing object creation and using the same objects repeatedly.

I am wondering if its similarly slow in other language with OOP base, because, to me, it is very counter intuitive that a language that's hardcore object oriented, takes so much time for object creation.

Has anybody profiled this on several langauges?

Comment: Some code samples would be nice.

Comment: I use a MacBook Pro with Core 2 Duo, 2.3 GHz, 2 GB RAM. I posted this as a general observation in several projects. If you haven't faced this problem, I would wait for others who have. :)

Comment: Perhaps tell us what kind of objects those are, simple pojos ? Heavy GUI objects ? something else ?

Comment: This goes against my experience, and probably many others.  If you want to make contentious assertions like this on SO, **you** need to provide some credible evidence to back them up.  (*"I have observed this in several projects ..."* is not credible evidence.)

Comment: Don't optimize if you don't have to.  If it really is a *measured* (profiler) perf *bottleneck* for your *entire* application that brings you below application or customer perf *requirements*, your time is better spent elsewhere.  And object pools are a very common solution to the slow nature of allocating objects on the heap.

Comment: I am not trying to create an argument here. I thought this was a general observation and thus wanted to get some ideas as to why this could be so.

Comment: @euphoria - the consensus is that you are wrong.

Comment: Java object creation is fast. This piece of code creates a 1 GB hashmap in memory, puts in 100 random elements and checks if 7 is there (impossible for JVM to optimize the object creation out). On my 2 core Pentium 4 machine it runs in 0.5 second.
http://pastebin.com/sRfXfPey

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try see what you get from this - some exercising to try to get the VM to not  optimize the loop away:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

class DummyInteger {
    private int i;
    public DummyInteger(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}

public class ObjectCreationTest {

    final static int ITERATIONS = 2000000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        int[] randArr = new int[ITERATIONS];
        for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            randArr[i] = r.nextInt();
        }
        DummyInteger[] iArr = new DummyInteger[ITERATIONS];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            ArrayList<DummyInteger> list = new ArrayList<DummyInteger>(); 
            list.add(new DummyInteger(randArr[i]));
            iArr[i] = list.get(0);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(String.format("Creating %d objects took %d ms",ITERATIONS*2,end-start));
        int sum = 0;
        for(DummyInteger mi: iArr) {
            sum += mi.getI();
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        }
}
```

I got

> Creating 4000000 objects took 678 ms

Which should be around 170 nanosecond per object.

Comment: I replaced the arrays with arrays of size 8, keeping ITERATIONS the same and using `% 8` in the index expressions.  Then moved the code into a method that I called a number of times.  This gave me an asymptotic time of 97ms to create 400,000 objects.  That is 24 nanoseconds per object.

Comment: Also bear in mind that each ArrayList instance actually contains a Object[], so we are really creating 3 objects per iteration.

Comment: I believe that the reason for the speed up when I reduce the array size is that we've *dramatically* reduced the number of objects that the GC has to trace.  In other words, most of the time in the original benchmark was running the GC ... and that's clearly not we were trying to measure.  Java micro-benchmarks are HARD to get right!!!

Comment: It's indeed very hard. Just be careful moving stuff too much around. My initial attempts ran in no-time, the optimizer was too smart and figured out ways to optimize parts of my loops just ocmpletely away.

Answer (score 10):

While there might be a [noticeable CPU impact](http://web.archive.org/web/20081223052756/http://www.christophkiehl.com/performance-tuning-object-creation-overhead) under rare circumstances, in general object creation for current virtual machines is as fast as it can practically be.

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04223.html) is an article I like called *"Urban performance legends"*, I think this is just one of those myths.

Also take a look at http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/rawtips.shtml for ideas of how to performance tuning your Java App.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for the Urban Performance legends link.  I also heard the mantra "object creation is slow" in Java at my first job in 2007... and that has stuck with me.