# Java - using functional interface and lambda expression to do logging

Tags: java, logging, lambda, functional-interface

Our traditional way to do logging is :

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("something to log, and barbarbar {}", object);
}
```

But what about using lambda expression to do logging to reduce lines of codes and complexity?

```
logger.debug(() -> return "something to log, and barbarbar " + object);
```

Is there any reason that slf4j or other logger do not provide this way to do logging? Object creation overhead caused?

Comment: Lambda expression are not free either. They take memory space too. This post has some comments and answers showing side effects you might have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682777/why-bother-using-lambda-expressions-in-logging-apis-if-the-compiler-can-possibly/47701408#47701408

Comment: You are right, this increase memory usage...
BTW I think the cost is low, and the object creation cost can be ignored
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485844/object-creation-in-java-is-slow/3485895#3485895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our traditional way to do logging is ...

It is not obligatory to use condition `logger.isXXXXEnabled()` in every use case. It's intended to be used only when you log an object that takes significant time to be created. For example when you need to put into log result of some DB query or complex structure converted to XML/JSON, etc.

For other cases this check is excessive.

Comment: sorry for my misleading sentence, please focus on "reduce lines of codes and complexity"